# Convert a csv/xlsx file to nc file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to convert a csv/xlsx to nc file format. In my csv file, I have date, lon, lats, and pm2.5 data. These represents multiple fire events emissions and therefore one date can have multiple events (lon, lats, pm2.5 data). When trying to create the variable pm2.5 with coords and dimensions, an error pops out:

> Could not convert tuple of form (dims, data[, attrs, encodring])... to variable.

I understand I have to reshape my pm2.5 array but the shape does not makes sense. I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd 
import xarray as xr 
import numpy as np 

from datetime import datetime as dt 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 
data= pd.read_excel('2020NEI_California.xlsx')
latitude=sorted(list(set( data['latitude'])))
longitude= sorted(list(set(data['longitude']))) 
time= sorted(list(set(data['date'])))

latitude, longitude, time
 
pm25 = np.array(data['pm25']).reshape(19384, .., ..)
 
#Creating xarray dataset
 
xrds= xr.Dataset(
    data_vars= dict(
        pm25=(["time", "latitude", "longitude"], pm25)
        ),

    coords= dict(
        longitude= longitude,
        latitude=latitude,
        time=time
        )    
    )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the shape does not make sense"? Also why are you making sets out of your lat, long and time and sort them afterwards? You loose all information on how your data belongs together.

Comment: Yes, so these emissions are for wildfires and prescribed burning events.. there can be different events on the same day but also different fire behaviours. For one wildfire event: you have one emission cell for wildfire/smoldering and one emission cell for wildfire/flaming. However, you can have multiple wildfires on the same day as well as prescribed burning events which makes it a little harder. My solution is to do nested if statements to add the different fire behaviours' emissions but I am also having trouble doing so.

Comment: Since you've successfully loaded the file to a dataframe, start your problem descriotion there.  Show the frame, or a summary - such as info,dtypes or header.  The goal,apparently, is to make a `xr` frame from the pandas.